# What should I do if I can't get a copy of original transcript from the institute?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, transcript-of-records

I saw an offer for a Ph.D. position in US where they asked for original transcript which directly should be sent from the home institute. When I asked my institute, they said they don't have these kind of options. In this case what can I do? Should I write the programme co-ordinator?

Comment: official transcripts from all previous colleges / universities attended

Comment: That's tough, my mother-in-law had similar problems.  In her case she had attended a communist-era Soviet school that had nothing for her.  Have you tried asking the school to send what they can for you?  If you've tried that, call the department at the school of interest and ask what they suggest.

Comment: They said if u need any seal,any letter,the university is ready to give it.But they never send anything via mail. May be I can write the supervisor again regarding this matter.

Comment: Yeah this seems like something you need to work out with your home institution; if they will not send it via mail, perhaps they can send it via fax or electronically? If so you could ask the program you are applying to if that would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should write the coordinator at the program you're applying to, explain the situation and ask for permission to submit a copy of your transcript (I assume you have one?) rather than an original. To remove doubt that you are playing some funny games, offer to append a notarized statement from you attesting to the authenticity of the document, and say you'd be willing to take any other reasonable measures they would like you to take to accept the document.

Since the school is in the U.S., I'm guessing they'll be reasonable.